Is an international student at greater risk of or from a cannabis possession charge in the UK?
Suppose Adam is an international student on a student visa in the UK. Suppose Adam is a recreational user of cannabis, hashish or similar, with no criminal history and no history (either on UK police record or in fact) of manufacturing or selling any controlled substance. Suppose Adam attempts to enter a venue while carrying a few grams of cannabis, hashish, or similar, and the bouncers confiscate the substance.
If the venue were to file a police report, how likely is Adam to be charged? Does Adam incur any additional risk because of his status as an international student?
I've read this answer on the general case.

Are you thinking of a greater likelihood of getting charged, or greater consequences e.g. regarding immigration status?

If they refuse admission to the venue, isn't the 'confiscation' theft? And if they let him in, he's no longer in possession of cannabis. So why would they bother to file a police report?

read here: https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/65a6b8ef867cd8000d5ae9b1/Criminality.pdf

@o.m. I'm interested in both.

@WeatherVane Is it theft to take without the owner's consent (TWOC) something the owner doesn't have a legal right to hold? I'm imagining they could file a police report if for whatever reason they're keen on enforcing laws against possessing cannabis, or because they take a disliking to the customer. Is part of your point that "possessing cannabis" is an offence but "having possessed cannabis" is not?

Bouncers can make a citizen's arrest, if they feel it is worth the effort (considering that they still need to mind the doors). But a witness to a crime can be put to a great deal of time and trouble making statements and visits to a police station, and there may not even be a decision to prosecute.

@thelawnet Thanks, that looks very useful. Do you happen to know how consistent the Home Office is about making the disposals mentioned at the bottom?

"they're keen on enforcing laws". They are doormen, not police or vigilantes, and it's a low level crime, for which a criminal conviction is now unlikely. Their job is only to ensure that the venue itself is a safe and law-abiding place.

"How likely is this law to be enforced?" is more of a political question than a legal one. Whether the punishment would be different, though, is a question that can be answered from the perspective of the law.
